REINFORCE Algorithm in Pytorch
I am trying to understand the REINFORCE algorithm and its implementation in PyTorch. While I am able to have the code work for the LunarLaner-v2 problem, I am not bale to join the dots between the theory and the code. Here's an excerpt from "Understanding Deep Learning" book by SJD Prince.

As per eqn 19.32 , once the rewards for an episode is collected , we need to calculate the discounted rewards for each step t from 0 to T-1. However , there is another round of multiplication by the discount factor gamma in eqn 19.33 at the time of gradient update.
Coming to the implementation, almost everywhere I looked, I found this logic ( or a similar variant ). The discounted rewards array is multiplied by the log-probs array, whilst the second discounting of eqn 19.23 doesn't happen at all.
# Helper function to calculate discounted rewards
def calc_disc_return(r_t , gamma = 0.998):

    G_t = deque(maxlen = len(r_t))
    G_t.append(r_t[-1])

    for i in reversed(r_t[:-1]):
        disc = i + (gamma*G_t[0])
        G_t.appendleft(disc)

    return np.array(G_t)

#Actual Gradient Update Step
def train(self, states, rewards, actions):
        
    state_t = torch.FloatTensor(states).to(device)
    action_t = torch.LongTensor(actions).to(device).view(-1,1)
    return_t = torch.FloatTensor(calc_disc_return(rewards, 
                       self.gamma)).to(device).view(-1,1)

    action_prob = self.policy_net(state_t).gather(1, action_t)
    loss = torch.sum(-torch.log(action_prob) * return_t)
    self.optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    self.optimizer.step() 

Can someone point at the gap in my understanding ?

You can find some answers here
